# XML parsing in iphone application

Tags: iphone, xml, xcode

I am beginner in iPhone development. I want to parse xml webservice in UITableView which will show  Result given in image file. How is it possible?  Please anybody provide any help how will I display that type of result in my table view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with NSXMLParser. Its a SAX parser. You will need to implement the delegate methods to fetch data and attributes from the XML. There are tons of blogs and tutorial explaining how to parse using NSXMLParser.

Comment: pls provide any url for better understanding

Answer (score 3):

Follow this , [how to parse XML in Objective c](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use) using ASIHTTPRequest and handle all this methods

```
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
```

See this [link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html) too